Error useSearchParams should be wrapped in a suspense boundary
AccountPage.tsx
"use client";
import { userColumns } from "@/components/data-table/user-columns";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Card, CardContent } from "@/components/ui/card";
import DataTableFetch from "@/components/data-table/DataTableFetch";
import { Suspense } from "react";

const AccountPage = () => {
  const fetchUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/users";

  return (
    <div className="flex h-full flex-col justify-around gap-4">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Accounts Page</h1>
        <Button variant="outline">Add Account</Button>
      </div>
      <Card className="h-full">
        <CardContent className="h-full">
          <DataTableFetch fetchUrl={fetchUrl} columns={userColumns} />
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AccountPage;

DataTableFetch.tsx
"use client";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react/dist/iconify.js";
import {
  useReactTable,
  getCoreRowModel,
  flexRender,
  ColumnDef,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import { usePaginationSearchParams } from "@/hooks/use-search-params.pagination";
import { useDebounce } from "@/hooks/use-debounce";
import { usePaginatedData } from "@/hooks/use-paginated-data";
import SkeletonTable from "../common/skeleton/skeleton-table";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import DataTableContent from "./DataTableContent";

interface DataTableProps<T> {
  columns: ColumnDef<T, unknown>[];
  fetchUrl: string; // URL for fetching data
  filters?: Record<string, any>;
}

const DataTableFetch = <T,>({
  columns,
  fetchUrl,
  filters = {},
}: DataTableProps<T>) => {
  // Manage pagination state via URL query parameters
  const [pagination, setPagination] = usePaginationSearchParams();
  const debouncedPagination = useDebounce(pagination, 300);

  const { pageIndex, pageSize } = debouncedPagination;

  // Use Suspense here for data fetching
  return (
    <div className="p-4">
      <DataTableContent
        fetchUrl={fetchUrl}
        columns={columns}
        filters={filters}
        pagination={{ pageIndex, pageSize }}
        setPagination={setPagination}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataTableFetch;

DataTableContent.tsx
import { usePaginatedData } from "@/hooks/use-paginated-data";
import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import SkeletonTable from "../common/skeleton/skeleton-table";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "../ui/table";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react/dist/iconify.js";

const DataTableContent = <T,>({
  fetchUrl,
  columns,
  filters,
  pagination,
  setPagination,
}: {
  fetchUrl: string;
  columns: ColumnDef<T, unknown>[];
  filters: Record<string, any>;
  pagination: { pageIndex: number; pageSize: number };
  setPagination: (pagination: { pageIndex: number; pageSize?: number }) => void;
}) => {
  const { pageIndex, pageSize } = pagination;

  const {
    data: fetchedData,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = usePaginatedData<T>(fetchUrl, {
    page: (pageIndex + 1).toString(),
    per_page: pageSize.toString(),
    ...Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(filters).map(([key, value]) => [key, value])
    ),
  });

  const totalPages = fetchedData ? fetchedData.total_pages : 0;

  const table = useReactTable({
    data: fetchedData ? fetchedData.data : [],
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  // Handle page change
  const handlePageChange = (page: number) => {
    if (page >= 1 && page <= totalPages) {
      setPagination({
        pageIndex: page - 1,
      });
    }
  };

  // Handle rows per page change
  const handlePerPageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setPagination({ pageSize: Number(event.target.value), pageIndex: 0 });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-4 flex justify-between">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="per-page" className="mr-2">
            Rows per page:
          </label>
          <select
            id="per-page"
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={handlePerPageChange}
            className="rounded border p-1"
          >
            <option value={10}>10</option>
            <option value={25}>25</option>
            <option value={50}>50</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>
            Page {pageIndex + 1} of {totalPages}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      {isLoading && <SkeletonTable />}
      {error && <p>Error loading data: {error.message}</p>}
      {fetchedData && (
        <>
          <Table>
            <TableHeader>
              {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
              {table.getRowModel().rows.length > 0 ? (
                table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                  <TableRow key={row.id}>
                    {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                      <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                        {flexRender(
                          cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                          cell.getContext()
                        )}
                      </TableCell>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                ))
              ) : (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell colSpan={columns.length} className="text-center">
                    No data found.
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>

          {/* Pagination Controls */}
          <div className="mt-4 flex items-center justify-end gap-4">
            <button
              onClick={() => handlePageChange(pageIndex)}
              disabled={pageIndex === 0}
              className={`rounded-full px-4 py-2 ${
                pageIndex === 0
                  ? "cursor-not-allowed bg-gray-300"
                  : "bg-blue-500 text-white hover:bg-blue-600"
              }`}
            >
              <Icon icon="bxs:chevron-left" className="h-5 w-5 text-white" />
            </button>
            <div className="flex space-x-2">
              {Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, index) => index + 1).map(
                (page) => (
                  <button
                    key={page}
                    onClick={() => handlePageChange(page)}
                    className={`rounded-full px-3 py-1 ${
                      page === pageIndex + 1
                        ? "bg-blue-500 text-white"
                        : "bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300"
                    }`}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </button>
                )
              )}
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={() => handlePageChange(pageIndex + 2)}
              disabled={pageIndex + 1 === totalPages}
              className={`rounded-full px-4 py-2 ${
                pageIndex + 1 === totalPages
                  ? "cursor-not-allowed bg-gray-300"
                  : "bg-blue-500 text-white hover:bg-blue-600"
              }`}
            >
              <Icon icon="bxs:chevron-right" className="h-5 w-5 text-white" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default DataTableContent;

usePaginationSearchParams
import { createParser, parseAsInteger, useQueryStates } from "nuqs";

// The page index parser is zero-indexed internally,
// but one-indexed when rendered in the URL,
// to align with your UI and what users might expect.
const pageIndexParser = createParser({
  parse: (query) => {
    const page = parseAsInteger.parse(query);
    return page === null ? null : page - 1;
  },
  serialize: (value) => {
    return parseAsInteger.serialize(value + 1);
  },
});

const paginationParsers = {
  pageIndex: pageIndexParser.withDefault(0),
  pageSize: parseAsInteger.withDefault(10),
};
const paginationUrlKeys = {
  pageIndex: "page",
  pageSize: "perPage",
};

export function usePaginationSearchParams() {
  return useQueryStates(paginationParsers, {
    urlKeys: paginationUrlKeys,
  });
}

useDebounce
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useDebounce<T>(value: T, delay = 300): T {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}

the error says
useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/dashboard/master-data/accounts"
when i wrapped the call on DataFetchTable on some page with <Suspense>..</Suspense>.
const AccountPage = () => {
 return (
     <div>
       <Suspense>
          <DataTableFetch fetchUrl={fetchUrl} columns={userColumns} />
       </Suspense>
     </div>

}
export default AccountPage;

It works. but why i should use that suspense, I still dont get the error, even though I'm not using the useSearchParams. I'm using nuqs also. In my root layout I already define the NuqsAdapter

Take a look at this solution: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/61654#discussioncomment-8480088

thank you for the reference it really helps
